# How to download a large array of long text files into Python without spliting by lines?

Tags: python

I hope someone could help with this problem. I have a folder with text articles in text form (.txt) and I need to dowload them to python with columns ***name of a file - whole text from the file in one slot*** for futher work with them.

So I need smth like that

```
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

But for 11 500 articles to be in 1 dataframe or another form

Comment: So, why do you split it then ?

Comment: @Kris i don't want to split them, i need dataframe where in 1 row will be name of file (1 column) and whole text of a file (2 column)

Comment: Please note: in programming, WORDS matter. DOWNLOADING typically refers to the process of connecting to a remote server/service and fetch data from there. The code you are showing OPENS a file locally. Those are two completely different things. Be PRECISE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just read and add them as rows. An example could be like

```
import pathlib
from pandas import DataFrame
SRC_DIR = pathlib.Path("./test-files") # Use your dir!
data_set = DataFrame()
for file in SRC_DIR.iterdir():
    data_set = data_set.append(dict(name=file.name, content=open(file, "r").read()), ignore_index=True)

print(data_set)
```

This generates a data frame like below

```
    name                                            content
0  a.txt  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...
1  b.txt  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...
2  c.txt  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...
```